# How to Hide/Remove "Premium Block" when adding new contribution?

Tags: civicontribute

Just wondering is there a way to update the contribution.tpl to hide the premium section please? I was not able to find in this tpl, thus asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this from the User Interface as far as I know. You would have to remove the block in a little extension. This is a small job but does require development skills.

Comment: can I not use a modified tpl in custom tpl directory?

Comment: Yes you can but I would not recommend it :-) You will have to check and update with each upgrade. But there is a template CRM/Contribute/Form/AdditionalInfo/Premium.tpl. I suspect if you copy this template to your own directory and make it empty or hide the div it would work. As said, not the recommended approach....